# BREAK BY With multiple joins in Progress ABL

Tags: progress-4gl

I am trying to learn Progress ABL and I can not find a good example of using break by with multiple joins.  The error I am getting right now is Colon followed by white space terminates a statement. (199).

The last time I ran into this error it was because I didn't have my end statement in the correct place, but I don't know if that is it or not.  Any help is appreciated.

```
DEFINE QUERY q1
    FOR platte.item FIELDS (item item_ptr costing_uom stocking_uom size description default_uom_conv_factor),
        platte.item_branch FIELDS (weight_uom load_uom weight load_factor),
        platte.item_uomconv FIELDS (system_id item_ptr_sysid),
        platte.uom_conv FIELDS (convert_from convert_to conv_factor),
        platte.product_group_minor FIELDS (major minor).

    OPEN QUERY q1
    FOR EACH item WHERE (item.system_id = '000000') NO-LOCK,
    EACH item_branch WHERE (item_branch.system_id = item.system_id
            AND item_branch.item_ptr = item.item_ptr) NO-LOCK,
    EACH item_uomconv WHERE (item_uomconv.system_id = item.system_id
        AND  item_uomconv.item_ptr_sysid = item.system_id
        AND item_uomconv.item_ptr = item.item_ptr) NO-LOCK,
    EACH uom_conv WHERE (uom_conv.system_id = item_uomconv.uom_ptr_sysid
                AND uom_conv.uom_ptr = item_uomconv.uom_ptr) NO-LOCK,
    EACH product_group_minor WHERE (product_group_minor.system_id = item.pg_ptr_sysid
            AND product_group_minor.pg_ptr = item.pg_ptr) NO-LOCK  BREAK BY item.item:

      DISPLAY
        item.item LABEL "item" "|SEP|"
        item.item_ptr LABEL "item_ptr" "|SEP|"
        item.size LABEL "size" "|SEP|"
        item.description LABEL "description" "|SEP|"
        WITH WIDTH 250.
      END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construct is incorrect - the last "END" statement doesn't belong, unless you change the OPEN QUERY for a FOR EACH .....like so:

```
FOR EACH item
    WHERE (item.system_id = '000000')
    NO-LOCK,

   EACH item_branch
       WHERE (item_branch.system_id = item.system_id AND
              item_branch.item_ptr = item.item_ptr)
       NO-LOCK,

   EACH item_uomconv
       WHERE (item_uomconv.system_id = item.system_id      AND
              item_uomconv.item_ptr_sysid = item.system_id AND
              item_uomconv.item_ptr = item.item_ptr)
       NO-LOCK,

   EACH uom_conv
       WHERE (uom_conv.system_id = item_uomconv.uom_ptr_sysid AND
              uom_conv.uom_ptr = item_uomconv.uom_ptr)
       NO-LOCK,

   EACH product_group_minor
       WHERE (product_group_minor.system_id = item.pg_ptr_sysid AND
              product_group_minor.pg_ptr = item.pg_ptr)
       NO-LOCK

   BREAK BY item.item:

   DISPLAY
           item.item LABEL "item"
           "|SEP|" VIEW-AS TEXT
           item.item_ptr LABEL "item_ptr"
           "|SEP|" VIEW-AS TEXT
           item.size LABEL "size"
           "|SEP|" VIEW-AS TEXT
           item.description LABEL "description"
           "|SEP|" VIEW-AS TEXT
       WITH WIDTH 250
           DOWN
           .
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the liberty of simplifying the example to use the well-known "sports2000" database.  To have a dynamic query that uses BREAK-BY and joins your code should be more like this:

```
define query q1 for customer, order scrolling.

open query q1 for each customer no-lock, each order no-lock of customer break by order.shipDate.

get first q1.

do while available customer:

  display customer.name order.shipDate.

  get next q1.

end.
```

1) To use BREAK-BY in a dynamic query you need that query defined as SCROLLING.

2) The OPEN QUERY statement should end with a ".", not a ":".

3) You have to actually fetch the data prior to displaying it.  GET FIRST and GET NEXT do that in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I've done any progress, but I'd be tempted to remove the terminal colon on this line

```
        AND product_group_minor.pg_ptr = item.pg_ptr) NO-LOCK  BREAK BY item.item:
```

Comment: Remove the break by and put it somewhere else?  I've tried using it inside a REPEAT: loop, but again same error.

Comment: I meant terminal colon, not column. As I said, not used progress in years - don't have access to a machine with progress now.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, but did give me a different error.  Unable to understand after item.item